# How to pass information from DeadboltHanlder to Controller-Method (Play Framework 2.8)

Tags: playframework, deadbolt-2, deadbolt

In our Play Framework application, we are using the **[Deadbolt](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2)** module for user authentication. This means that the `getSubject()` method of our DeadboltHandler-implementation will be called **before** the actual Controller method. However, we need to transport the determined User-ID from the DeadboltHandler's `getSubject()` method to the Controller method.

Up to and including Play Framework 2.6 this could easily be done by adding the User-ID to the `HttpContext.args`, because the `HttpContext` was available in `getSubject()` as well as in the Controller-Method. Unfortuately, in Play Framework 2.7 and later, there **no** longer is a `HttpContext` - we have to work with `HttpRequest` directly. But it seems that `HttpRequest` is immutable; we cannot add the determined User-ID to `HttpRequest` easily.

Yes, there is `Http.Request.withAttrs()`, but this does not modify the `HttpRequest` object but instead returns a new `HttpRequest` object. So this is **not** helpful for passing any information from `getSubject()` method to the Controller method, as far as I can tell.

***So, what is the recommended way to pass Request-specific information from the DeadboltHandler to the Controller-Method in Play Framework 2.7+ ???***

Controller class:

```
public class MyController extends Controller
{
    @SubjectPresent
    public CompletionStage<Result> search()
    {
        final Subject subject = Thingamabob.currentSubject();
        /* I need something like this ^^^ */
    }
}
```

DeadboltHandler implementation:

```
class public class MyDeadboltHandler extends AbstractDeadboltHandler {
    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Optional<? extends Subject>>
            getSubject(final Http.RequestHeader request) {
        final Subject subject = determineSubjectFromRequestHeader(request);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Optional.of(subject));
    }
}
```

**Note:** The method `MyDeadboltHandler.subject()`, which determines the `Subject`, is called ***implicitely*** by the framework *before* the actual controller method will be called.

Thanks you and best regards.

Comment: Have you tried to use filters https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaHttpFilters#Filters? You can inject DeadboltHandler instance, modify request with `Http.Request.withAttrs()` and pass modified object to next filter.

Comment: Can you give some more detail please? The `getSubject()` method of the DeadboltHandler implementation - which is called ***implicitely*** before the controller method - has *one* parameter of type `Http.RequestHeader`, and it has return type of `Optional<? extends Subject>`. So, when implementing this method, I *have* to return a Subject. How would I go about "pass modified object to next filter"? I really see no way to do this from the DeadboltHanlder...